# How to convert vector<int> to a char array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Platform is Windows with MSVC.  I'm writing an encryption unpadding function.

I have many `vector<int>` which are the results of a decryption function.  A `vector<int>` might contain a UTF-8 string, or it might be garbage if the decryption parameters were wrong.  I need to subtract a number from each position, and then see if it's a valid UTF-8 string.  That's the [padding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)): add a character's position to itself before encrypting.

To display the results, I assume I need to convert the `vector<int>` to a `vector<char>`.  I can then use that as a `const char[]` and print it to the console.

How do I handle the possibility of overflow and underflow when casting to a `char`?  After all, a `char` is signed and has a range of -128 to 127 on my platform.

```
std::vector<char> unpad(const std::vector<int>& input) {
    std::vector<char> output;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        if (input[i] < -128 || input[i] > 127) {
            printf("oops overflow\n");
        }
        output.push_back(static_cast<char>(input[i] - i)); // Padding scheme
    }
    output.push_back(static_cast<char>(0)); // Null termination
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Throw an exception would seem to be the obvious thing to do. Something like `if (input[i] < -128 || input[i] > 127) {
            throw std::logic_error("decryption failure");
        }` Need to `#include <stderror>` for `std::logic_error`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at this problem wrong. You don't want to cast from int to char since you'll lose information. You want to preserve the information in the int. What you need to realise is that an int is 32 bits and char 8 bits. Therefore you need 4 chars to hold all the information from a single int. To extract the information from a single int you need to use bit operators

```
char a = some_int & 0x000000ff;
char b = some_int & 0x0000ff00;
char c = some_int & 0x00ff0000;
char d = some_int & 0xff000000;
```

Now you'll have the 4 bytes (the chars) that map to the parts in a single int. You can work from there to decode utf-8.

Note that on 64 and 32 bit systems ints take 4 bytes.

Comment: Side note: An `int` on the vast majority of non-embedded, modern systems is 32 bits, but the only guarantee you get about the size of an `int` is it's no smaller than a `short`, no smaller than 16 bit, and no larger than `long`. If you need guarantees use the [fixed width integers defined in <cstdint>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)